# Add multiple attributes based on *ngIf in Angular2?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

Is it possible to add multiple attributes based on `*ngIf`?

My pseudo Code:

```
<span *ngIf="msg.active" *ngIf="msg.error"  >Hallo</span>
```

And my output should be like this:

If `msg.error == false` and `msg.active== true` then it should be like this:

```
<span>Hallo</span>
```

If `msg.error == true` then it should be like this:

```
<span class="error" myTag="false" myTag2="false" >Hallo</span>
```

If `msg.active == false` then the span tag should be empty!

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try using nested ternary operator.

```
<span *ngIf="msg.active==true && msg.error==false? true: msg.active"> hallo <span>
```

try your condition using ternary operator. hope this will work

for myTag you have to use separate *ngIf

Answer (score 0):

altogether in a single line it is possible as shown here,

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/eKDhkuf3JO8CIKfz7Eqz?p=preview**

```
<span *ngIf="msg.active || msg.error" 
       [class.error]="msg.error"> 

       {{(msg.active==false)?'':'hello'}}

</span>
```

Comment: How can I set 'myTag="false"' and  'myTag2="false"'

Comment: Are they variables or properties of an object?

Comment: They are variables

Comment: Then you can use them separately.